# Importing user to AD in OU using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a piece of powershell script that loops thru the name of users and adds them to Active Directory into an OU (organizationalUnit), but I have a problme : by some reason I can't add users to that organizationalUnit. I get an error on create user, which says that object is empty, so in other words I think my connection string doenst seems to work , I tried everything and dont know how to solve.

Just a notice when I do the same but for cn it does add users but for OU not ...

Here is the piece of script:

```
$Connection = "LDAP://ou=SopraUsers,dc=sopragroup,dc=lan"

        # Get A Unique Password

        [string]$Password = Generate-Password
        $username=$Firstname.substring(0,1).toLower() + $Surname.toLower().replace(" ", "")
        # Create User in AD

        $container =[ADSI] $Connection
        $User = $container.Create("User", "cn="+$username)
        $User.Put("sAMAccountName", $username)
        $User.Put("givenName", $Firstname)
        $User.Put("sn", $Surname)
        $User.Put("mail", "")
        $User.Put("displayName", $Firstname + " "+$Surname)
        $User.SetInfo()


        $User.PsBase.Invoke("SetPassword", $Password)
        $User.PsBase.InvokeSet("AccountDisabled", $false)
        $User.pwdLastSet = 0
        $User.SetInfo()
```

I think the problem is in `$Connection = "LDAP://ou=SopraUsers,dc=sopragroup,dc=lan"`
because if I do `$Connection = "LDAP://cn=Users,dc=sopragroup,dc=lan"`

Then i do get people added but only for Users.

Here is how my AD looks like, as you can see I want ppl get added to the lowest OU.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you give the exact Error message please ?

Answer (score 1):

Just put this line in comment :

```
$User.Put("mail", "")
```

If you don't want to put an email address just remove this line ; on my server it gives a bad attribute syntax.

---

As far as the connexion string is concern, can you try this connexion string ?

```
"LDAP://sopragroup.lan/ou=SopraUsers,dc=sopragroup,dc=lan"
```

You can create a connexion like this :

```
$Connection  = [adsi] "LDAP://sopragroup.lan/ou=SopraUsers,dc=sopragroup,dc=lan"
```

or, if you want to authenticate :

```
$Connection  New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://ServerIP/ou=SopraUsers,dc=sopragroup,dc=lan","administrator@sopragroup.lan","pwd")
```

Comment: yes seems like ok for me too, and as i said it works with creating user onder cn but when i put instead of cn, OU it just doesnt work, says something like create cant be called, but ill post error soon

Comment: I modify my answer, I think you can try this connexion string.